# Bootstrap 5, me and ms classes

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have a problem with **me** and **ms** classes, im learning how to create navbar and in this situation the **elements one and two** should work with **ms** class(be left-aligned) and **elements three and four** should work with **me** class(be right-aligned), but instead it works as centered:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Company Name</a>
  </div>

  <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Element one</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Element two</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Element three</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Element four</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How it works: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcWhl.png)

How it should work: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7ycA.png)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? At least provide a sketch/wireframe of the layout you're going for

Comment: My bad sorry, edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read up how `.me-auto` and `.ms-auto` works in Bootstrap 5. Position utilities have changed with Bootstrap 5. It uses the new [CSS Logical Properties and Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties). Also see Bootstrap's documentation on Auto margins [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins).

#### TLDR

- **`.ms-auto`** (`margin-inline-start: auto`) ≈ `.ml-auto` (`margin-left: auto`)
- **`.me-auto`** (`margin-inline-end: auto`) ≈ `.mr-auto` (`margin-right: auto`)

Setting a `margin-left: auto` on an element (in a flex container) will align the element to the **right**, not left. The **opposite** is true for `margin-right: auto`.

#### Example: Navbar using auto margins

This is how you'll correctly implement the *spaced-apart* layout using auto-margins (You actually did it correctly in the first version of your question).

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Element one</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Element two</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Element three</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Element four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

#### Navbar using justify-content

You can also achieve the same effect by adding `.justify-content-lg-between` to the parent `.collapse` class. This basically sets `justify-content: space-between` on screen sizes above the mobile (`lg`) breakpoint. I feel this is a better way to implement the intended layout but it's good to know both.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div
          class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-lg-between"
          id="navbarNav"
        >
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Element one</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Element two</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Element three</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Element four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: thank you, for some reason I thought .me should be at the end and .ms at the start